# Selenium Python cannot select Element on ConnectWise Login Page

Tags: python, html, selenium

Hi I am trying to select the Company Box on the Connectwise login page to automate a login.

However I have trouble even selecting the Company Field.

[image]

The **Element** that needs selecting:

```
<input class="loginTextBox loginTextBox-watermark" type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off"/>
```

**What I have tried:**

Tried **XPATH**:

```
company_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/x:html/x:body/x:div[6]/x:div/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[1]/x:td/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[2]/x:td/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[1]/x:td/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr/x:td[2]/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[1]/x:td/x:input")
```

Stack Trace:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression /x:html/x:body/x:div[6]/x:div/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5en9.png)/x:td/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[2]/x:td/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5en9.png)/x:td/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr/x:td[2]/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5en9.png)/x:td/x:input because of the following error:

Tried **Class Selection**:

```
company_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name("loginTextBox loginTextBox-watermark")
```

Stack Trace:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted

Tried **CSS**:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".loginTextBox loginTextBox-watermark[type='text']").click()
```

Stack Trace:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".loginTextBox loginTextBox-watermark[type='text']"}

**HTML Source of Page:**

```
<document>
<html>
<head>
<body style="background-color: #F2F2F2; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;" ondragover="window.event.returnValue=false;">
<iframe id="__gwt_historyFrame" style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0" tabindex="-1" src="javascript:''"/>
<script src="common/scripts/cw.js?v=201561" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="common/scripts/cw.io.js?v=201561" type="text/javascript"/>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">     function checkSsl() {         if (document.location.protocol != "https:" && document.location.host.indexOf("localhost") == -1 && document.location.href.indexOf("dotnet") == -1) {             cw.io.jsonCall("login/IsSslRequired.rails", { 'onsuccess': function (data) {                 if (data.Data == true) {                     var url = "https://" + document.location.host + document.location.pathname + document.location.search + document.location.hash;                     document.location.href = url;                 }             }              });         }     } cw.ui.createInitialLoadingNode();         checkSsl(); document.writeln("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='com.connectwise.psa/com.connectwise.psa.nocache.js'></scr" + "ipt>"); function dragover(e) { return false; } </script>
<div id="cw-loading" class="cw-loading">
<script src="com.connectwise.psa/com.connectwise.psa.nocache.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"/>
<iframe id="com.connectwise.psa" src="javascript:""" style="position: absolute; width: 0px; height: 0px; border: medium none; left: -1000px; top: -1000px;" tabindex="-1"/>
<div style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true"/>
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20cm; width: 10cm; height: 10cm; visibility: hidden;" aria-hidden="true"/>
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
<div class="GHN3134DCB" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: block; width: 1366px; height: 659px;"/>
<div class="GHN3134DJB" style="left: 435px; top: 163px; border-width: 0px; z-index: 555555555; position: absolute; overflow: visible; background-color: transparent;">
<div class="popupContent">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
<table class="GHN3134DK5I" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
<table class="GHN3134DJ5I" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="display: block;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
<td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
<input class="loginTextBox loginTextBox-watermark loginTextBox-hightlight" type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</document>
```

Would appreciate any help?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression /x:html/x:body/x:div[6]/x:div/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr1/x:td/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr[2]/x:td/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr1/x:td/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr/x:td[2]/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr1/x:td/x:input

This error occurred because provided `xpath` syntactically incorrect.

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted

This error occurred because selenium doesn't support compound class to locate an element.

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".loginTextBox loginTextBox-watermark[type='text']"}

This error occurred because you are locating incorrect element. According to locator it would be try to locate `<loginTextBox-watermark>` element which attribute `type` has value `text` and should be descendant of an element which has class attribute value `loginTextBox` which is incorrect.

So basically your all provided locators are syntactically or logically incorrect, you should try using correct `css_selector` locator as below :-

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.loginTextBox.loginTextBox-watermark.loginTextBox-hightlight[type='text']")
```

Or if `<table>` class name `GHN3134DJ5I` is unique and fixed, you can try also as :-

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table.GHN3134DJ5I input.loginTextBox.loginTextBox-watermark.loginTextBox-hightlight[type='text']")
```

**Css Selector reference** : to [learn more about `css_selector` follow this reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

**Xpath reference** :  : to [learn more about `xpath` follow this reference](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time Saurabh! I have much to learn.